# Click event on words react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to set different click listeners on different words of . Currently what i have is

```
<Text>Android iOS React Native<Text>
```

Now i want to know when user click on Android, iOS and React Native, i have to perform some analytics on that so need click listeners for seperate words.

Does any one have idea about it? I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718143/react-native-add-bold-or-italics-to-single-words-in-text-field) thread but i din't found it useful for my requirement.

**Update**
String i have given is just an example string, in real time i will be getting dynamic strings.

This is what i will be getting as dynamic string

```
{
    "str":"Hi i am using React-Native, Earlier i was using Android and so on"
    "tagWords":["React-Native","Android"]
}
```

And in output i want, "Hi i am using **React-Native**, Earlier i was using **Android** and so on"

with click event on "React-Native" and "Android". Is is possible?

Comment: Are the methods dynamic as well? Can you provide some context to what you want

Comment: There must be some API call in which u will be getting some response and then u want to display that accordingly

Answer (score 7):

The post you sent is the simplest way you can achieve the desired behavior. Sinse you need to have different listeners you need to implement different `Text` components.

**Example**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  onTextPress(event, text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          <Text onPress={(e) => this.onTextPress(e, 'Android')} style={styles.red}>{'Android '}</Text>
          <Text onPress={(e) => this.onTextPress(e, 'iOS')} style={styles.purple}>{'iOS '}</Text>
          <Text onPress={(e) => this.onTextPress(e, 'React Native')} style={styles.green}>{'React Native'}</Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  red: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'red'
  },
  purple: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'purple'
  },
  green: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'green'
  }
});
```

**Update 1** *(Dynamic text)*

```
  render() {
    const fixedString = 'I\'m a fixed string that slipleted';
    const arrayOfStrings = ['These', 'are', 'strings', 'from', 'array'];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textContainer}>
        {
          fixedString.split(' ').map((str, index) => {
            return (
              <Text onPress={(e) => this.onTextPress(e, str)}>
                {`${str}${index !== (fixedString.split(' ').lenght -1) && ' '}`}
              </Text>
            )
          })
        }
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.textContainer}>
        {
          arrayOfStrings.map((str, index) => {
            return (
              <Text onPress={(e) => this.onTextPress(e, str)}>
                {`${str}${index !== (arrayOfStrings.lenght -1) && ' '}`}
              </Text>
            )
          })
        }
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

**Update 2** (for example dynamic data)

```
  removePunctuation = (text) => {
    // this is a hack to remove comma from the text
    // you may want to handle this different
    return text.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\_`~()]/g,"");
  }
  render() {
    const arrayOfObjects = [{
      str: 'Hi i am using React-Native, Earlier i was using Android and so on',
      tagWords: ['React-Native', 'Android']
    }];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textContainer}>
          {
            arrayOfObjects.map((obj) => {
              return obj.str.split(' ').map((s, index) => {
                if ( obj.tagWords.indexOf(this.removePunctuation(s)) > -1 ) {
                  return (
                    <Text onPress={(e) => this.onTextPress(e, s)} style={styles.red}>
                      {`${s} ${index !== (obj.str.split(' ').lenght - 1) && ' '}`}
                    </Text>
                  )
                } else return `${s} `;
              })
            })
          }
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: String i have given is just an example, i am having dynamic string, so how can i perform that, i know by using 3 `<Text>` we can do it, but how can we do it with dynamic string?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya updated question with dynamic text example but I must say if the text is long or if you have lots of listeners like these you may have some performance issues since every word creates a new listener and a new function.

Comment: @bennygenel you explained that pretty well, performace issues will be there. An exact scenario will help us giving a proper answer.

Comment: @devanshsadhotra exact scenario is i might have string like "Hi i am using React-Native, Earlier i was using Android and so on" where words "React-Native" and "Android" i will be getting in seperate array so i have to perform actions based on that.

Comment: So , is there any specific set of words over which you want to perform some action?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya can you update your question with a better representation of your example. like how does your dynamic data look like, which part are dynamic etc.

Comment: @bennygenel sorry for misleading, i have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

all you need to use is TouchableOpacity(for the tap effect and clicks), View for the alignment of texts. and certain styling. I am providing you the code snippet that will work for you , all other syntax will remain same

```
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={{()=>doSomethingAndroid()}}>
        <Text>Android</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={{()=>doSomethingiOS()}}><Text> iOS</Text> 
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacityonPress={{()=>doSomethingReactNative()}}><Text> React Native</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

i hope this works, comment back if any issue happens

Comment: String i have given is just an example, i am having dynamic string, so how can i perform that, i know by using 3 `<Text>` we can do it, but how can we do it with dynamic string?

Comment: if the value is coming from backend , then you must do like, :   <Text>
                      {operatingSystem}
                    </Text>
in operatingSystem key u must fetch the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap each clickable words into '**TouchableOpacity**' component, and tract the onPress event as follows

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
        console.log('Android Clicked');
      }}>
      <Text>Android</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
       console.log('iOS Clicked');
     }}>
     <Text>Ios</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Please do adjust the spacing between words.

**Edit:**
For dynamic string you can proceed as follows

```
...

handleWordClick(str, handler) {
 var words = str.split(' '), // word separator goes here,
     comp = [];
 words.forEach((s, ind) =>{
     comp.push(
       <TouchableOpacity key={ind} onPress={() => handler.call(this, s)}>
          <Text>{s}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       );
 })
 return comp;
}

render() {
  var comp = this.handleWordClick('Android iOS React-Native', (word) => {
      //handle analytics here...
      console.log(word);
      });
  return (
    <View>
     ...
     <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
       {comp}
     </View>
     ...
     </View>
    )
}
```

I am not sure what will be your **word separator** as the example you have given has 'React Native' as single word. Please pay attention on this part.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: String i have given is just an example, i am having dynamic string, so how can i perform that, i know by using 3 `<Text>` we can do it, but how can we do it with dynamic string?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I have edited my answer for dynamic string, I am not sure whether it will serve your purpose or not, but expecting this will help you.