# How do I make text bold, italic, or underline in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-text

Surprisingly there isn't one question that groups these all together yet on Stack Overflow; there hasn't been an answer on SO for italics or underline, in fact, only [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718143/react-native-add-bold-or-italics-to-single-words-in-text-field) for bold. I self-answered this question below.

Comment: BTW it's clearly given in the react-native docs on how to perform all these together, so why should people ask a question?.

Comment: @RaviRaj 50 people upvoted this, so it would seem people find value in this post. Stackoverflow is about finding answers quickly without having to scour through docs. What potential downside do you see?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

```
<Text style={styles.bold}>I'm bold!</Text>
<Text style={styles.italic}>I'm italic!</Text>
<Text style={styles.underline}>I'm underlined!</Text>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bold: {fontWeight: 'bold'},
    italic: {fontStyle: 'italic'},
    underline: {textDecorationLine: 'underline'}
})
```

Working demo on Snack: https://snack.expo.io/BJT2ss_y7

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I am copying the idea into [es.so]: [¿Cómo pongo negritas, cursiva o subrayado en React Native?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/293594/83)

Answer (score 80):

In this Example of React Native Underline Text, we will see how can you underline the Text using the Stylesheet property textDecorationLine.

```html
<View style={styles.MainContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.TextStyle}>Example of Underline Text</Text>
</View>
```

```js
TextStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
    fontStyle: 'italic'
    fontSize: 20,
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    //line-through is the trick
},
```

There are other decorations :

1. none
2. underline
3. line-through
4. underline line-through

Answer (score 23):

use only

```
<Text style={styles.textStyle}>I'm Underline!</Text>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textStyle: {
    textDecorationLine: 'underline'
  }
})
```

Other decorations are :

1. none
2. underline
3. line-through
4. underline line-through

Answer (score 12):

Only one line solution

```
<Text style={{fontStyle: 'italic', fontWeight: 'bold', textDecorationLine: 'underline'}}>Bold, Italic & Underline Text</Text>
```

Comment: textDecorationLine does it for me!

Answer (score 8):

You can see all possible att in this page
https://reactnative.dev/docs/text

for example ...

```
textDecorationLine: enum('none', 'underline', 'line-through', 'underline line-through')
```