# Styles in react-pdf showing abnormal behaviour

Tags: css, reactjs, text-styling, react-pdf

I'm trying to use italic styling in react-pdf.

Everything works well until I use `font-style: italic;`.

Is there another way style text as Italic in react-pdf ?

```
const Italic = styled.Text`
  font-size: 12px;
  lineheight: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  font-style: italic;//problem is with this line
  font-weight:400;
`;
```

It is giving me the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not resolve font for undefined, fontWeight 400

Comment: try putting font-size, lineheight and letter-spacing in double quotes (font-size: "12px") or single quotes etc. Though the suffix px is not needed. React will automatically append a “px” suffix to certain numeric inline style properties. If you want to use units other than “px”, specify the value as a string with the desired unit.

Comment: nothing happens @IVANPAUL

Comment: Apologies forgot, to add that font-style : "italic" should also be in double or single quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50556938/6033636 refer to this answer for more

Answer (score 6):

When you register your fonts, you need to make sure to include a variant for each `fontStyle` you wish to use. For example:

```
Font.register({
  family: 'Roboto',
  fonts: [
    { src: '<path-to-normal-font-variant>' },
    { src: '<path-to-italic-font-variant>', fontStyle: 'italic' },
    ...
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Tom. This worked for me and saved me time.

Answer (score 2):

```
const Italic = styled.Text`
  font-size: "12px";
  lineheight: "20px";
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  letter-spacing: "0.5px";
  font-style: "italic";//problem is with this line
  font-weight:400;
`;
```

where ever you are suffixing px needs to be in either single or double quotes and font-style: value(italic) need to be in double quotes as well.