How can i make a class italic using pdf react renderer?
I want  to style a class of a text, in a way  my text gets in italic.
I've imported the Roboto font, with plenty styles, yet I can't  make it italic.
This is my "css" (It's not exactly css  because it's the styling in the react-renderer-pdf  library)
  Inspection: {
    top: 15,
    left: 55,
    fontFamily: "Roboto",

    fontSize: 7,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  } 

This way works
  Inspection: {
    top: 15,
    left: 55,
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
    fontStyle: "italic",
    fontSize: 7,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  } 

this way it doesnt
I've shared a print of how  my fonts  are structured in my project.

Have you had a look around to see if there is useful info already on SO? For example, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60705386/styles-in-react-pdf-showing-abnormal-behaviour

This question is similar to: Styles in react-pdf showing abnormal behaviour. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Make sure you've registered the italic font correctly in react-pdf
import { Font } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
Font.register({
  family: 'Roboto',
  fonts: [
    { src: 'path/to/Roboto-Regular.ttf' },
    { src: 'path/to/Roboto-Bold.ttf', fontWeight: 'bold' },
    { src: 'path/to/Roboto-Italic.ttf', fontStyle: 'italic' },
  ],
});

Then apply:
Inspection: {
  top: 15,
  left: 55,
  fontFamily: "Roboto",
  fontStyle: "italic",
  fontSize: 7,
  fontWeight: 'bold'
}

