# How we can bold some words in TextInput component React Native?

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-native-textinput

I want something feature in textInput like if we write hello then hello should be bold in the textinput and remaining words will be normal. Can someone help me out with it?

It's something different from Text Component, which mentioned in below link.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718143/react-native-add-bold-or-italics-to-single-words-in-text-field
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native add bold or italics to single words in <Text> field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718143/react-native-add-bold-or-italics-to-single-words-in-text-field)

Comment: No, it's for Text Component and I am talking about TextInput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make custom textInput component, something like this:

```
const [txt,setTxt] = useState("");
        <Pressable>
            <TextInput placeholder="Type Something..." onChangeText={(value)=>setTxt(value)}/>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    {txt.split(" ").map((text)=><Text style={{fontWeight:text == "bold"?'bold':null}}>{text+" "}</Text>)}
                </View>
        </Pressable>
```

Replace `text == "bold"` with any value that you want to make bold.

**Edit**: if you want to make more than one word bold, group them in an array and update your condition like this:

```
const anArrayOfBoldStrings = ["bold","hello","stackoverflow"];

            <Pressable>
                <TextInput placeholder="Type Something..." onChangeText={(value)=>setTxt(value)}/>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        {txt.split(" ").map((text)=><Text style={{fontWeight:text == anArrayOfBoldStrings.includes(text?'bold':null}}>{text+" "}</Text>)}
                    </View>
            </Pressable>
```